# Line breaks in Django rest response

Tags: html, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I see that in JSON response "\n" doesn't work for string values as 
below. Is there any specific way for this in Django-rest Framewore. I am using "BrowsableAPIRenderer" from Django rest framework.

```
{
  "count"   : "10",
  "results" : [
    {
      "id" : "10",
      "output" : "line1 \n line2 \n line3"
    },
  ]
}

HTML Code

<pre class="prettyprint">
...
...
 <span class="str">
 "line1 \n line2 \n line3"
 </span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape the backslash character so that `'\n'` is sent as your response. In your example, try
replacing the value associated with the `"output"` key:

```
"output" : "line1 \\n line2 \\n line3"
```

Comment: It doesn't work, It is printing as like "output" : "line1 \\n line2 \\n line3". I tried with <br> but no luck.

Comment: Where are you printing this? onto an HTML?

Comment: Yes, <pre class="prettyprint">
...
...
 <span class="str">
 "line1 \n line2 \n line3"
 </span>